# samsung xcover 4, has no internet access while connected to a specific wifi network

Tags: wi-fi

It seems I'm facing a strange problem with my smartphone.
After the last update, I can't connect to my office's wifi. All the other devices connect normally. However, I tried resetting the router many times. 
On the other hand, my phone connects perfectly to all other networks. I think I did everything possible, even a hard reset, but the problem insists.
 I've tried changing the IP settings to static and typing my IP etc, but nothing worked.
Any other ideas are welcome.

thanx

Update : When I walk 15 meters away from my desk to another office and try to connect again, my phone connects normally to the same network but from a different router. So, I suppose the problem is between my nearby router and my phone. Is there any way to fix this? It worked till last Friday, so there's no chance of incompatibility.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Not a solution, but maybe a way to find the culprit: did you [check the logs](/tags/logging/info)? If not, please do so. Then please [edit] your question and include relevant findings. Or [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) if those findings led you to a solution already :)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you should upgrade your Android OS version, most of the time this method work for me.

Comment: All this mess was caused because of the last software update. If there was a way to cancel this, I would have done it for sure. I tried to check for any new update that may fix the problem, but the latest updates are already installed. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps you can downgrade your existing OS manually. How about using Odin and find your previous OS Android version on the net or on the website such as SamMobile. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. Just bought a brand new router. I was totally defeated.